# Completely different line break with different fonts

Tags: fonts, errors, footnotes, programming, reledmac

**reledmac feature under development**

I am building a new footnote arrangement for footnotes in reledmac (with the help of the maintainer). reledmac can typeset footnotes in two columns or in "paragraph mode." (These two tricks were already presented in the TeXbook (pages 395--400).

The code that implements the `twocolpara` footnote arrangement is in [issue 655](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commits/issue655) of `reledmac` repository.
At the moment the arrangement works more or less, but we noticed that it depends on the font.

These two images show the output of a test file ([`examples/1-criticalnotes.tex`](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/blob/issue655/examples/1-criticalnotes.tex)) in libertine (using the package `libertineotf`) and pagella (using the package `tgpagella`) compiled with `xelatex`.

[image: Typeset with libertine]
[image: Typeset with TG Heros]

Notice that when typeset with libertine we get a decent paragraph (not perfect, there is too much or too little space after a footnote), but using heros, the 3rd footnote start a new line when there is enough space in the previous line.

*NOTE:* I know that this is not a simple error that can be covered in a MWE. I hope someone is intrigued enough with the example files, that will be willing to look at the code.

The code is a mix between the code used in the `twocolumn` and `paragraph` arrangements. It is on lines 10721--10889 of `reledmac.dtx` file in the mentioned branch.

The code can be obtained:

```
$git clone https://github.com/maieul/ledmac
$cd ledmac
$git checkout issue655
$make reledmac.sty
```

The examples are in the `examples` subfolder. An easy way to compile them with the changed reledmac is to make a link in `examples` pointing to the `reledmac.sty` generated previously.

Comment: If it's too much work for *you* to provide a test file/MWE when you're demonstrably  part way there, consider how much more work it would be for anyone wanting to help you.

Comment: Dear Chris, thanks for the comment. I post the NOTE to let people know I am aware of the convention of posting MWEs. All the code is in the github branch I linked. Following your comment, I will add some more info on how to get the code.

Comment: It's clear that the relevant `reledmac` code is there.  It's not clear that there's runnable test code there.  A link to an MWE is a good thing (IME) when it's big, but only if that's obvious.

Comment: The example file name now links to the actual file in the repository. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Well naturally paragraphs depends on the font. The question is what is so bad in your settings. So try to make a an example that typesets a paragraph of this size with the settings you use in footnotes.

Comment: That should work.  It initially wasn't clear (without following the link) that you were linking to a work-in-progress version of `reledmac`, let alone to anything we could use to test it.

Comment: Dear @UlrikeFischer, the problem is related to a `reledmac` feature which is work-in-progress, so it is not related to the settings. The problem is that the footnote mechanism, boxes and unboxes the footnote text several times; and obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @TeXtnik: At the end of the chain there is badly typeset paragraph. And you need to understand why it is so bad.

Comment: `tgpagella` is not going to be using Heros, as you claim, unless there is something seriously wrong with your copy. Do you mean `tgheros`? Why are you loading either package if you are using XeTeX? Those packages are configured to use the postscript type 1 fonts. For libertine, new documents should use `libertine` rather than `libertineotf`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for noticing! I mistakenly assumed that `tgpagella` uses `otf` fonts for XeLaTeX! Using `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}`or using `pdflatex` gives a better paragraph. (But the column balancing is not yet good). If you make your comment an answer, I will acept it.

Comment: @TeXtnik That's not because you are using OTF rather than type 1, though, is it? The example you showed was not using `tgpagella` at all, was it? So what are you comparing with what? Type 1 Pagella and OTF? Or Type 1 Heros and OTF Pagella?

Comment: @cfr: You are right, sorry. I made so may combinations with fonts! The sample with `Heros`, either Type 1 or OTF (even using xelatex with `tgheros`, look very similar. But with `Pagella` using `tgpagella` with `xelalex` looks much worse than the correct combinations of `pdflatex` + `tgpagella` package or `xelatex` with the OTF fonts.

Comment: Is there any news here?